# Color I pick in Texture Paint mode is different from the actual paint color

Tags: texturing

What should I do to make the color I pick for texturing match the actual color?
Don't really know how to say it any more specific :)

[image]

Comment: You mean that color in the top pick is what you want and that yellow down right is what you get? Or is it different on model in 3d viewport?

Comment: Yes, the yellow color on the bottom of the screen shot is what I see when I draw with the color on the top of screenshot